# Meteor App is not running on android emulator

Tags: android, meteor, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have installed jdk and created avd. After running command meteor run android --verbose, it is saying no emulator specified defaulting to nexus_5.
After running this command : `emulator -avd emulator-5584`
I am getting -

> HOME is defined but could not find emulator-5584.ini file in
>   $HOME/.android/avd (Note: avd is searched in the order of
>   $ANDROID_AVD_HOME,$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/avd and
>   $HOME/.android/avd)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to create an avd (Android Virtual Device), although the fact that you are specifying an id for the emulator suggests you already have one called emulator-5584?

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment . I got the solution my $PATH was not right. Thank you for your time. I am closing this question.